# Android: QuickContactBadge in the ListView

Tags: android, listview, quickcontactbadge

First the scenario:

I have a list where each item has a photo of a contact and some text. I would like to click on the image and bring up the `QuickContactBadge`. Badge is defined by the following XML snippet

```
<QuickContactBadge android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/badge" 
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></QuickContactBadge>
```

What I tried and failed:

1. Define one reusable badge and reuse it for all cases. Both list and badge are placed into `RelativeLayout`
2. Have one badge defined per each list item. The item uses `RelativeLayout`

What do I see:

Basically nothing. The code gets valid badge instance and then I apply the following logic

```
    contactPhoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Image click");
            if (badge != null) {
                badge.assignContactFromEmail("johndoe@gmail.com", true);
                badge.setMode(ContactsContract.QuickContact.MODE_SMALL);
                badge.bringToFront();
            }
        }
    });
```

As I click I can step through the code in `onClick` handler yet the badge never comes up

The questions:

1. Does `QuickContactBadge` have any placement logic? When I click on the image do I need to calculate badge position and readjust or is it built-in?
2. Is it possible to achieve what I describe above (badge for images displayed in the list) and what I'm doing wrong (or missing)

Comment: So #1 is yes. QuickContactBadge does not have placement logic but it triggers the Intent that does calls QuickContact which calculates the Rect based on where the screen was clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abort! Abort!

Basically I totally misunderstood what the badge is and how to use it. What I was trying to do is to detect click on image and call the badge. This is fundamentally wrong since all I needed to do was to simply use `QuickContactBadge` INSTEAD of `ImageView` in my code. After I replaced images with badges in the item XML magic was automatically there.

Said that - it is possible to pop the badge using the code, refer to [this article](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/fe9c4c7e5c8a85df) on how to do it

Comment: @Droidln.net can you please look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340039/contact-list-with-contact-photo-creates-performance-issue , using this code i am getting different size of QuickContactBadge